# adding HTML markup and PHP echo to PHTML file

Tags: html, syntax, php

I have this code on my PHTML file:

```
<?php
function showChildrenCategories($_category, $level, $level_limit, $columns,    $custom_html=''){
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$html = '';
if($level == 0) {
    $html .= '<ul id="nav" class="megamenu">';
    $html .= '<div class="mobnav-customer-admin"></div>';

}  else {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'.$level.'">';    

}
$_children = $_category->getChildren();
$children_ids = explode(",", $_children);
$i = 0;
$categoryChildren = array();   
if ($children_ids) {
    foreach ($children_ids as $categoryId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $categoryChildren[] = $category;
    }
}
?>
```

On line 7, I have created the HTML container (.mobnav-customer-admin) and within that container, I would like to echo some content, using PHP.

This is what I want to echo:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea, how to put that piece of PHP in that HTML container, that I have created above. I also break the syntax, whatever I try.

This all comes from a Magento installation. Can anyone tell me how I get my HTML container and how I can add that content to the container, without breaking the syntax?

Comment: What is the problem? `$html .= '<div class="mobnav-customer-admin">'.$this->getChildHtml('topLinks').'</div>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$html .= '<div class="mobnav-customer-admin"></div>';
```

to

```
$html .= '<div class="mobnav-customer-admin">'.$this->getChildHtml('topLinks').'</div>';
```